# Flutter 3.16.0 CustomPainter issue

Tags: flutter

I have a `customPainter` class which draws a row with a date string. This `customPainter` class is used in a ListView.Builder inside the `itemBuilder` method. It is used like so.

Database query to check if entry exists.

```
pickerDatePicker = CupertinoPicker.builder(
      key: const Key('datePickerKey'),
      itemExtent: 30,
      selectionOverlay: null,
      diameterRatio: 1.5,
      onSelectedItemChanged: (val) {
        currentDateTimeIndex = val;
        //print('onSelectedItemChanged called');
      },
      childCount: 20000,
      scrollController: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 10000),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Jiffy drawDateTime = _calcJiffyDate(index, nextTuesday);
          int drawMillis = drawDateTime.dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
          r.RealmResults<EuroMillionsDraws> exists = widget.statistics.query('${EuroMillionsDrawsConstants.FIELD_PK_DRAWN_DATE} == $drawMillis');

        print('itemBuilder called: database row is empty: ${exists.isEmpty}');

        if (exists.isEmpty) {
          
          print('Text color should be red');
          
          return CustomPaint(
            key: Key('datePickerKey$index'),
            size: Size(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
            painter: DrawnDatePainter(
              drawnDateString: dateFormatter.format(drawDateTime.dateTime),
              textColor: Colors.red[200]!,
            ),
          );
          
        } else {
          
          print('Text color should be blue');
          
          return CustomPaint(
            key: Key('datePickerKey$index'),
            size: Size(
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            ),
            painter: DrawnDatePainter(
              drawnDateString: dateFormatter.format(drawDateTime.dateTime),
              textColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          );
          
        }
      },
    );
```

The only difference is a different text color for the `CustomPainter` when returning a `CustomPaint` object depending if a database row exists or not.

Now the `CustomPainter` updates its color value and the Cupertino entry is also repainted but the color doesn't change, only if a close the dialog and reopen the dialog then the colors are correct.

Comment: Did I understood correctly that it prints 'Text color should be blue' but the text is 
really red? This is just a guess but does it matter if you change key: Key('some different key'), so that it does not reuse the widget or something like that

Comment: Could be a state management related issue. Did you manipulate the data of the table and the color did not change?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my self.
The problem was that i used showDialog. In this case i should wrap AlertDialog inside a StatefulBuilder, otherwise the state is never changed. So simply wrap the AlertDialog with a StatefulBuilder and you re good to go. Hope this helps somebody.

Thanks again.